# Gravity Vs Distance

Tags: newtonian-gravity, distance

What is the relationship between the magnitude of Earth's gravity and the distance away from the Earth's surface? Or at what rate does gravity decrease as one moves away from Earth?

Comment: [Newton's Universal Law of Gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_universal_gravitation) is an extremely accurate model of the relationship between the magnitude of gravity from a spherical body and distance from the spherical body's center.

Comment: Have you done any searching?

Comment: insufficient prior search of the internet, since a simple search should give the answer to this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The gravity g from a body of mass m at d distance from the center of the body can be found by the equation g = (m × G) / (d<sup>2</sup>), where G is the universal gravitational constant.

Usually, g is in meters per second<sup>2</sup>, m is in kilograms, d is in meters, and G is in meters<sup>3</sup> per kilogram per second<sup>2</sup>.

If you want to apply this to the Earth, the Earth's mass is 5.972 × 10<sup>24</sup> kilograms, the universal gravitational constant is 6.67384 × 10<sup>-11</sup> meters<sup>3</sup> per kilogram per second<sup>2</sup>, and the surface of the Earth is 6,731,000 meters from the center of the Earth.

Answer (score 0):

The force of Earth's gravity is inversely proportional to the square of the distance to the Earth.

Comment: Square of the distance to the center of the earth.   :-)